# Rails 5.2: Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, babeljs

I am facing a issue when executing `async / await` in javascript and get an error `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`.

Below is relevan part of my js code.

```
  async function initExport() {
    let getData = await getVizData('Lateral Map', 0);
    let myUpload = await s3Upload();
    return myUpload();
  }
```

Relevant part of my gem is below:

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'xray-rails'
end

group :production do
  gem 'sprockets-rails'
  gem 'sprockets'
  gem 'babel-transpiler'
  gem 'passenger'
end
```

if it is of any help then below are the relevant contents of my `Gemfile.lock`

```
    babel-source (5.8.35)
    babel-transpiler (0.7.0)
      babel-source (>= 4.0, < 6)
      execjs (~> 2.0)
```

I am facing this issue on my `development` environment. Any help on how to fix this would be really great.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can see, this question has nothing to do with Rails – and thus shouldn't mislead the reader into thinking it is. I suggest you remove the Rails references and tags accordingly.

Comment: Hi Clemens, sorry may be i was not very clear, its a rails 5 application in which i am seeing the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need [regenerator-runtime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regenerator-runtime).

Just following the instructions in its REAMDE should solve your problem.

Comment: Can you please let me know i can i integrate it in a rails 5 application.